# Convert a lambda expression back to inner classes?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am having the following lambda expression:

```
Function<Integer, Function<Integer, Function<BinaryOperator<Integer>, Integer>>> someComputation = i1 -> i2 -> f -> f.apply(i1, i2);
```

Java 8 lambda syntax is still a bit unfamiliar to me so I tried to convert it back to inner classes but it seems that I can not be converted it throws a compilation error or maybe I am missing something. 
Here is how I think it is:

```
    Function<Integer, Function<Integer, Function<BinaryOperator<Integer>, Integer>>> someComputation2 = new Function<Integer, Function<Integer, Function<BinaryOperator<Integer>, Integer>>>() {
        @Override
        public Function<Integer, Function<BinaryOperator<Integer>, Integer>> apply(Integer integer) {

            Function<Integer, Function<BinaryOperator<Integer>, Integer>> f = new Function<Integer, Function<BinaryOperator<Integer>, Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public Function<BinaryOperator<Integer>, Integer> apply(Integer integer) {


                    return new Function<BinaryOperator<Integer>, Integer>() {
                        @Override
                        public Integer apply(BinaryOperator<Integer> integerBinaryOperator) {
                            return integerBinaryOperator.apply(f,""" WHAT IS IN HERE ???""");
                        }
                    };



                }
            };

            return f;
        }
    };
```

Comment: even if lambda syntax is not familiar to you, it is not a reason to replace 1 readable line with a tonne of boilerplate code

Comment: @AndrewTobilko If the new syntax is confusing, one of the greatest ways to understand it is to transform it back to something that you already know. Don't bash on learning.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I am not doing this in a code ... I am only learning and just got confused ... here is the article that I am trying to understand

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/partially-applied-functions-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two `Integer` variables in the methods of the outer anonymous class instances. Those are the variables that should be passed to the inner most method call :

```
Function<Integer, Function<Integer, Function<BinaryOperator<Integer>, Integer>>> someComputation2 = new Function<Integer, Function<Integer, Function<BinaryOperator<Integer>, Integer>>>() {
    @Override
    public Function<Integer, Function<BinaryOperator<Integer>, Integer>> apply(Integer i1) {
        Function<Integer, Function<BinaryOperator<Integer>, Integer>> f = new Function<Integer, Function<BinaryOperator<Integer>, Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public Function<BinaryOperator<Integer>, Integer> apply(Integer i2) {
                return new Function<BinaryOperator<Integer>, Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public Integer apply(BinaryOperator<Integer> integerBinaryOperator) {
                        return integerBinaryOperator.apply(i1, i2);
                    }
                };
            }
        };
        return f;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Eclipse or other equivalent Java IDE, you can generate some skeleton code, then wire the implementation you want. Something like you would expect is

```
Function<Integer, Function<Integer, Function<BinaryOperator<Integer>, Integer>>> someComputation = new Function<Integer, Function<Integer,Function<BinaryOperator<Integer>,Integer>>>() {

        @Override
        public Function<Integer, Function<BinaryOperator<Integer>, Integer>> apply(Integer t1) {
            return new Function<Integer, Function<BinaryOperator<Integer>,Integer>>() {

                @Override
                public Function<BinaryOperator<Integer>, Integer> apply(Integer t2) {
                    return new Function<BinaryOperator<Integer>, Integer>() {

                        @Override
                        public Integer apply(BinaryOperator<Integer> t3) {
                            return t3.apply(t1, t2);
                        }
                    };
                }
            };
        }
    };
```